# Can someone help fix my code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So here is my code:

```
with open('lines.txt') as f:
for i in f:
    line = input('line: ')
    if line not in i.split('\n'):
        print(line, i.split('\n'), end='\n')
    else:
        continue
```

It's supposed to fetch lines from a text file and ask me to type the first, second, third, etc. Until there are no more lines in the file, and if I get a line wrong, it prints 'No!' but it says 'No!' for every single input I enter, so what do I have to do to make this code work?

Comment: Hey! [Glad to see you wrote some code :)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18555902/1971805)

Comment: Should it re-ask for the same line if given wrong input? Currently it doesn't, it asks for the next line. The last two lines don't do anything significant.

Comment: Nop, if it's wrong, it ask for the second line, well, it's *suppose* to

Comment: So you type in the whole line or just word by word? And if you get a line wrong, do you move onto the next one or stay on the same one until you get it right?

Comment: Maybe you could try printing out the line and the entered line for debugging.

Comment: You type in the full line, if it's wrong, it moves to the next line :)

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer I tried what You suggested, and it is the most amazing thing.. it actually worked :D kind of, I edited my question for you to see!!

Comment: So what do you get when you run that code? It should show you why it rejected the input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice try! Here is a solution using the useful `rstrip` method of string to take care of those pesky newline characters. This does what you want, asking for input line by line, and if you get it wrong, it moves onto the next one.

```
with open('lines.txt') as f:
    for i in f:
        i = i.rstrip()
        line = input('line: ')
        if line != i:
            print('No!')
```

Answer (score 3):

`.split()` returns a list. You probably meant to check whether the line is *in* the list.

Do:

```
if line in i.split('\n'):
```

Comment: Yup, I tried, that, didn't work though, and I need to make sure it's the first or second or third line, so they have to be in order, do you have any more tips? :)

Comment: @samir In any of the lines? Then you might want to get the whole file's content by doing `f.read()` and split that. Then you can do `if line in i.split('\n')`

Comment: @samir Or, you can do `if any(line in x for x in i.split('\n')` using the [`any`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) function

Comment: I did `for i in f.read():` and the code you suggested, it works for the first line, and anything at all, and it goes on forever, so I can write 100 wrong answers, is there a different approach to do it other than my way, which isn't too complex?

Comment: @samir I am no expect at this, but perhaps the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module may be handy. I have had no experience with it though, and it might not even be the way to go. Just thought I could throw it in

Comment: With the `any` function it says No! to any first string, and on the other lines it passes it, but it does the correct amount of lines

Comment: You probably mean `strip` not `split`

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing a string to a list in the line

```
    if line != i.split('\n')[0]:
```

You could try comparing to the first element in the array:

```
    if line != i.split('\n')[0]:
```

Or if you can safely ignore leading and trailing spaces:

```
    if line != i.strip()
```

The else block you have will present a second, unchecked input after every correctly entered line, was that what you intended?

Answer (score 1):

Are you supposed to just match the whole line? In which case all you want is

```
if line != i.strip():
```

If you need to ignore double spaces etc. It is more complicated, you will need to do the following:

```
match = True
myWords = line.strip().split()
fileWords = i.strip().split()
for myWord, fileWord in zip(myWords, fileWords):
  if myWord != fileWord:
    match = False
if Match:
  line = input('line: ')
else:
  print('No')
```

Does the problem require you not to move onto the next line if you get an error??